# Color points if ID in vector in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have imported data in this form:

```
Sample1 Sample2 Identity
1    2    chr11-50-T
3    4    chr11-200-A
v <- read.table("myfile", header = TRUE)
```

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
x <- c(50,100)
```

And without some other aesthetic stuff I am plotting column 1 vs column 2 labeled with column 3.

```
p <- ggplot(v, aes(x=sample1, y=sample2, alpha=0.5, label=identity)) +
geom_point() +
geom_text_repel(aes(label=ifelse(sample2>0.007 |sample1>0.007 ,as.character(identity),''))) +
```

I would like to somehow indicate those points that contain a number in their ID, found within the vector `x`. I was thinking this could be done with color, but it doesn't really matter to me as long as there is a difference between the two types of points.

So for instance if the points containing a number in `x` were to be colored red, the first point would be red because it has `50` in the ID and the second point would not be, because `200` is not a value in `x`.

Comment: @MikeH. yes i am doing point and i added in some of the other pieces of the call which is the current labeling i'm doing.

Comment: I notice that your question uses both sample1 and Sample1.  R is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add in a `TRUE/FALSE` value as a column and use that as a color. I had to remove your `label = ...` aes since that's not an `aes` in `ggplot2`. Also everything is transparent because you use `aes(alpha = 0.5)`:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)

vafs$col <- grepl(paste0(x,collapse = "|"), vafs$Identity)

p <- ggplot(vafs, aes(x=Sample1, y=Sample2, alpha=0.5, color = col)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=ifelse(Sample2>0.007 |Sample1>0.007 ,as.character(Identity),'')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following solution:

```
vafs<-read.table(text="Sample1 Sample2 Identity
       1    2    chr11-50-T
       3    4    chr11-200-A", header=T)

vec <- c(50,100)

vafs$vec<- sapply(vafs$Identity, FUN=function(x) 
ifelse(length(grep(pattern=paste(vec,collapse="|"), x))>0,1,0))

vafs$vec <- as.factor(vafs$vec)

ggplot(vafs, aes(x=Sample1, y=Sample2, label=Identity, col=vec),alpha=0.5)+geom_point()
```